# Swift - Custom UIImageView class

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift3, xcode8

I was trying to find an answer to my question but couldn't find anything helpful.

I have an app that contains a lot of views, all views have at least one UIImageView. I need some of them to have UIBlurEffect on it, but I don't want to make an outlet for each and then create few lines of code for each to get desired blur.

**My question is:** 
How can I do this using custom UIImageView class (or another way)?

I have also tried doing this by creating extension for UIImageView and making `@IBInspectable` but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a custom subclass of UIView that contains an image view, plus your UIVisualEffects (blur) view, and anything else you want.

You could expose an IBInspectable image property in this custom subclass and have the custom view install the image into it's child image view.

Comment: I like your answer - extensions won't work here - but I'm curious why you chose UIView and not UIImageView (with a full sized blur on it).

Comment: @dfd, The OP said "all views have at least one UIImageView". That suggests to me a group of views that **has** an image view, not an image view that has child views.